next js image styles not applying
i'm new to next.js and was using it with tailwind CSS for my portfolio site. I was basically done my portfolio site when I decided to delete the image cache for whatever reason. After I reran my dev server almost everything on my portfolio looked the same, but for some reason the images I had in my timeline weren't styled anymore. They used to be rounded in a single row and resized with the page, but now they appear in separate rows with no styling and they use the original width/height I sent to the next prop. Does anyone know why this happened? I used next image in another part of my portfolio but nothing happened to it, which has me more confused. Also, when I inspect I see the styles. Any help appreciated, thanks.
Inspect:
inspect pic
Layout after deleting next:
now layout
code:
<div className="grid grid-cols-2 gap-4 text-gray-50 font-bold">
<Image
  src="/assets/digitera-landing.png"
  alt="digitera home page"
  width={500}
  height={800}
  className="h-full rounded-xl object-cover shadow-lg drop-shadow-2xl"
/>
<Image
  src="/assets/digitera-techs-stacked.png"
  alt="languages used"
  width={500}
  height={800}
  className="h-full rounded-xl object-cover shadow-lg drop-shadow-2xl"
/>
</div>


If the CSS code you wrote is not applied, you should use !important. This is possible by writing ! in front of tailwind css. You can find its usage in the tailwind documentation.

This is terrible advice..
